# solve the positive integers $(m,n)$ such $(F_{m})^m=((F_{n})^n+1)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, diophantine-equations, fibonacci-numbers

Suppose $F_n$  to be the nth term of the Fibonacci sequence.($F_1=F_2=1,F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n$)

(1)Find all  duals $(m,n)$, so that $$F_m^m=(F_n^n+1)^2$$.
(2)Find all triples $(m,n,t)$, so that $$F_m^m=F_n^n(F_t^t+2)+1$$.

for (1):since $$F_{3}=2,F_{4}=3,F_{5}=5,F_{6}=8,\cdots,$$
if $m=2$,then $(F_{m})^m=1$,then not solution,because $RHS>1$

if $m=4$,then $9=F_{4}^2=(F_{n})^n+1$,then $n=3$,so $(m,n)=(4,3)$ is solution

if $m=6$,then $ 8^3=(F_{n})^n+1$, it is clear no solution

Gerry Myerson point that can use [Catalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture):since $F^n_{n}+1$ can't  be a power for $n>3$.so $n>3$ the equation can't have solution

so for (2) problem  maybe can't use this result?

Comment: It's known that no two consecutive positive integers are both powers, except for the integers eight and nine. So $F_n^n+1$ can't be a power for $n>3$, so $(F_n^n+1)^2$ can't be a power higher than a square, so it can't be $F_m^m$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,Thanks,